# Error bar out of plotting range when using R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is an example of my problem:

```
library(ggplot2)

x = 1:10
y = rep(5,10)
y_err = rep(2,10)
limits <- aes(ymax = y+y_err, ymin=y-y_err)

data <- data.frame(
  x = x,
  y = y
)

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_pointrange(limits) +
  ylim(0, 6)
```

I got the following warning messages

```
Warning message:
In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  Removed 10 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

This is because my data + error = 5 + 2 = 7 is out of the plotting range ylim(0,6).

But instead of drawing truncated error bars, ggplot doesn't draw error bars at all. Is there a way to still keep the same ylim and draw truncated error bars (at 6)?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 6))` rather than `ylim(0,6)`. See duplicate.